# gridfs- stream doesn't delete files from mongdb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, gridfs

I am trying to update a profile picture, but i read GridFS has no update method so i am trying to first delete the record then insert the new one later, but when i try to delete the record, it says "success"  but doesn't delete it at all from DB( record still visible), when i added gfs.exist just as a check before deletion, i get the following log, i don't understand why its returning false, when the record does exist and i did try passing the filename too( same error).

```
 console.log("current pid:",req.body.current_pid);
 gfs.exist({_id:req.body.current_pid}, function (err, found) {
  console.log("found: ", found);
  if(found){
         gfs.remove({_id:req.body.current_pid}, function (err) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log('success in deletion',err);
            });
  }
  else{
    console.log('does not exist',err);
  }
  });
```

}

Logs:

```
current pid: 55b877629f6f5af41c0e25ed
found:  false
does not exist null
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an object that exists with that `_id`? gridfs-stream "should" autocast to an ObjectId. Unless you defined a different namespacde for your GridFS objects you should be able to find it in the shell with: `db.fs.files.find({ "_id": ObjectId("55b877629f6f5af41c0e25ed") })` in the database you are connecting to. BTW, `.remove()` takes two arguments in the callback, with the second being the number of deletions. No error doesn't mean something was deleted.

Comment: i did `db.photos.files.find({ "_id": ObjectId("55b877629f6f5af41c0e25ed") }).pretty()` and it does return a object, and i am new to gridfs- stream, can u please give me an example for using .remove() (with its correct syntax)

Comment: Looking at a different namespace than "photos.files" maybe? Try commenting out your exists and try to fetch the object in the same place. Also look for the code where wrote the file. And the `.remove()` method basically wraps [unlink](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/GridStore.html#unlink) in the core API. So the callback can be `function(err,result)` where you check "result".

Comment: Are you setting the `.collection()` name to "photos" in any of your code? If not then it is still looking in "fs"

Comment: do i need to change it to look in photos.files?? but gridfs should handle it automatically right?

Comment: You need to change it. GridFS expects the default collection "root" to be "fs", so do the methods in gridfs-stream. That's your problem. Just set that method from the "gfs" object `gfs.collection("photos")` in your code and it will be find. Otherwise the extra arg to the individual methods take a config object, so: `{ "root": "photos" }` there.

Comment: i added root attribute to options json and it deleted the object fine 
**root:'resume'**
`gfs.remove({_id:req.body.current_rid, root:'resume'}, function (err) {})`
Thanks @BlakesSeven. your comments made me think deeper, really appreciate it

Comment: Thanks! i was looking for this! adding the "root" into the option works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it. GridFS expects the default collection "root" to be "fs", so do the methods in gridfs-stream. That's your problem. Just set that method from the "gfs" `object gfs.collection("photos")` in your code and it will be find. Otherwise the extra arg to the individual methods take a config object, so:

`{ "root": "photos" }`

there.

credits - @blake seven